# AngularJS: Renderizar componentes causa loop de requisições

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net

Estou trabalhando com um projeto legado, escrito em AngularJS 1.5.8 e ASP.NET 4.5.

Com o objetivo de atualizar o ClientSide do projeto para Angular, o primeiro passo que tive que tomar foi de componentizar o sistema.

Porém, estou enfrentando um problema quando tendo renderizar algum componente, como por exemplo:

```
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini fixed" md-no-ink>
<div class="wrapper" style="height:calc(100%)" loading-listener column="row" flex>
    <div style="height:calc(100%)" class="display-hidden" ng-class="true ? 'display-block':''">
        <div layout="row" style="height:100%">
            <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
            <div flex>
                <div layout="column" flex>
                    <div flex>
                        <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
                    </div>
                    <main flex>
                        @RenderBody()
                    </main>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ao tentar renderizar qualquer componente, como no caso, a sidenav e o toolbar, ocorre o problema, não gera nenhum erro, porém fica em um loop de requisições, carregando todos os componentes de novo e de novo, quando isso ocorre o navegador até para de responder aos comandos, como fechar por exemplo, não trava, porém tenho que encerrar o processo pois o botão não executa a ação.

Agradeço desde já quem puder me ajudar.

Edit 01 - Adicionei o código .js do componente appTopMenu.

```
angular.module('messageModule')
.component('appTopMenu', {
    templateUrl: 'components/message-component/message.template.html',
    controller: ["$scope", "$mdToast", "$location", "$rootScope", "CommonService", "Enums",
        function MessageController($scope, $mdToast, $location, $rootScope, CommonService, Enums) {
            $rootScope.AppInfo = Enums.AppInfo;
            $rootScope.$on("user:loggedin", function () {
                $scope.mensagens = [];
                $mdToast.hide();
            });

            $rootScope.Sair = function () {
                $rootScope.loggedUser = false;
                CommonService.autenticacao.sair().$promise.then(function () {
                    location.reload();
                });
            };

            $rootScope.$on('user:notlogged', function () { $rootScope.Sair(); });
            $scope.mensagens = [];
            $scope.icone = Enums.MsgIcon;
            $scope.cor = Enums.MsgColorContext;

            $rootScope.reqsActive = 0;
            $rootScope.closeToast = function () {
                $mdToast.hide();
            };

            xhook.after(function (request, response, callback) {
                callback();
                $rootScope.reqsActive--;

                if (request.url !== 'go/autenticacao' && response.finalUrl.indexOf('go/Autenticacao') >= 0) {
                    $rootScope.$emit("user:notlogged");
                }
                $rootScope.url = $location.path();
                if ($rootScope.reqsActive === 0) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast("loading:completed");
                }

                var data = {};
                try {
                    if (response.headers['content-type'].indexOf("application/json") < 0) {
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (response.data.indexOf("{\"Messages\":[]") < 0)
                            data = JSON.parse(response.data);
                        else
                            return;
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    return;
                }

                var htMessages = [];
                if (data.Message && true) {
                    data.Messages = [];
                    data.Messages.push({ Type: "E".charCodeAt(0), Message: data.Message });
                    data.Messages.push({ Type: "E".charCodeAt(0), Message: data.ExceptionMessage });
                }

                if (data && data.Messages && !data.NotInterceptable) {
                    $.each(data.Messages,
                        function (i, msg) {
                            tipo = String.fromCharCode(msg.Type);
                            htMessages.push('<div class="md-toast-content progress-bar-striped alert-' + $scope.cor[tipo] + '">' +
                                '<span class="md-toast-text" flex>' + msg.Message + '</span>' +
                                '<md-button ng-click="$root.closeToast()"> OK </md-button>' +
                                '</div>');
                            $scope.mensagens.push({ tipo: tipo, texto: msg.Message });
                        });

                    var el = $("body")[0];
                    if (data.Messages.length)
                        $mdToast.show({
                            parent: el,
                            template: '<md-toast style="z-index:90007">' + htMessages.join("") + '</md-toast>',
                            hideDelay: 8000,
                            position: "top right"
                        });
                }
            });

            $rootScope.$broadcast("loading:completed");

            xhook.before(function (request, callback) {
                request.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache";
                callback();
                if ($rootScope.reqsActive === 0) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast("loading:started");
                }

                $rootScope.reqsActive++;
            });
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Teria o Javascript pra adicionar à pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVIDO

No fim das contas, estava faltando subir um diretório a mais no templateUrl.

Alterei de: `templateUrl: 'components/message-component/message.template.html'`

para: `templateUrl: 'SPA/components/message-component/message.template.html'`

E tudo voltou a funcionar novamente.

Tanta procura por algo tão básico heheh espero que possa ajudar alguém que passe pelo mesmo.